# Create Plot in NetLogo

Tags: arrays, netlogo

I'm beginner in Netlogo, I want creat a plot for all patches, I don't use turtle I use juste the patches, for each patches I have 3 variables (patche-own Area1, Area2, Area3). I want my plot contains the surface occupied by patche (for eache Area)==> 3 pens in the plot.
I need for help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make an attempt at it, however small and post here, what you come up with.

Comment: Add a plot to the interface and fill in the variable names. Honestly, while this can be done with code, you should be doing it with the interface tools (the dropdown box that is labelled 'button' when you open)

Comment: Thanks for your ansewer, yes I did all that but I'm stuck in code of update commands.

Comment: What Himanshu said.